# Intellisense для javascript в vs code не работает с require

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

При добавлении require в файл intellisense в нем просто пропадает.

Берем vs code,
Создаем два файла .js
Файл номер 1:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Файл номер 2:
[image]
Все как и должно быть

Добавляем в файл 1 одну строчку: `require("fs");`
Теперь intellisense не работает в файле 2
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а почему во втором случае должна была быть подсказка с TestFoo?

Comment: @Grundy Конкретно в моем случае я использую electron, поэтому у меня смешан код для браузера (оба файла подключены как <script>) и для node.js, могу ли я как-то принудительно включить подсказки?

Comment: Может поможет `const fs = require("fs");`?

Comment: Можно попробовать что-то в настройках посмотреть. Скорее всего видя наличие `require` vscode считает этот файл модулем, соответственно в другом файле он не виден уже